# Call to undefined method Imagick::getImageOrientation()

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

Hoping that someone could provide some insight on what might remedy this error please.

I'm getting the following error when trying to use getImageOrientation via PHP/imagick:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Imagick::getImageOrientation()
```

I'm running:

- PHP 5.3.28
- imagick module version => 3.1.2
- ImageMagick version => ImageMagick 6.2.8 04/25/12

[Official PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimageorientation.php) indicate a PECL 2.0.0 requirement, but I don't understand what that means. [PHP PECL Docs](http://pecl.php.net/package-info.php?package=imagick&version=2.0.0RC3) indicate that `getImageOrientation()` was added in 2.0.0RC3, so shouldn't it be working since I'm using 3.1.2?

Alternatively, I understand that I can use a combination of `exif_read_data()` and `switch` to achieve the same effect (detection of exif orientation and rotating the image) but I believe that function reads the file again, which is undesired as I already have an $image object in place to do `strip()` and `thumbnailImage()` the image.

To add to the confusion, I attempted to upgrade to 3.2.0RC1 via cpanel but it says that this is the same version that's already installed. Do I have any other options or do I need to install something else elsewhere (apache, etc)?

Thanks kindly for any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Imagick is just a wrapper around ImageMagick, it doesn't provide any real functionality itself.

The function getImageOrientation was added to ImageMagick in version 6.3.3 which was released on 24th of February 2007.

Upgrading to a version of ImageMagick that is less than eight years old would be a good thing to do.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Danack . Unfortunately, it's unclear to me what impact upgrading ImageMagick will have on the cpanel-based pecl install of imagick. That is, I'm worried that upgrading ImageMagick manually via command line will break the ability to use imagick which was setup by cpanel. Either now or when cpanel / pecl imagick updates.

Comment: Theoretically Imagick should only be used with the version of ImageMagick that it was compiled against. In practice mixing and matching versions 'seems' to work. However if you're on a hosted service, you probably shouldn't be upgrading it yourself. Instead you should get your hosting company to upgrade the software they provide.